# Finding a dictionary from its contents

Tags: python, dictionary, grid, maze

I'm trying to create something to prove the concept that moving through a maze with your left hand on the wall works, so I've made a python 3.6 turtle program to do it. It's extremely inefficient, I know, I'm a beginner, but my question is;
How would one find the name of a dictionary from it's contents.

Here's an example:

```
place1 = {"coordinates" : (150, 150), "filled_in": False}
place2 = {"coordinates" : (100, 100), "filled_in": True}
place3 = {"coordinates" : (50, 50), "filled_in": True}
turtle position = 50, 50
```

Essentially, something like this

`?["coordinates" : (50, 50), "filled_in" = True`

I want to be able to find the dictionary from the value within it, so I can check if it's filled in.

```
if (dictionary containing value of "coordinates" : (50, 50))["filled_in"] = False:
    do whatever
```

I understand I've probably formatted everything wrong, but thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put them all in one dictionary that can be indexed by the coordinate:

```
place1 = {"coordinates" : (150, 150), "filled_in": False}
place2 = {"coordinates" : (100, 100), "filled_in": True}
place3 = {"coordinates" : (50, 50), "filled_in": True}
places = {p["coordinates"]: p for p in [place1, place2, place3]}
```

And then just index it:

```
>>> places[(50, 50)]['filled_in']
True
>>> places[(150, 150)]['filled_in']
False
```

Comment: Really helpful. Now I just face the problem of having 64 dictionaries. As I said, poorly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `'coordinates'` key of your dictionaries:

```
for d in (place1, place2, place3):
    if d['coordinates'] == (50, 50):
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will elaborate on @MSeifert's answer. Let's say you have 64 variables like following:

```
place1, place2, ..., place64
```

Just replace this:

```
places = {p["coordinates"]: p for p in [place1, place2, place3]}
```

With:

```
places_list = ["place{}".format(num) for num in range(1, 65)]
places64 = eval(str(places_list))
places = {p["coordinates"]: p for p in places64}
```

That being said, using of [eval is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). Consider loading coordinates from separate file for example.

Comment: Instead of `eval` use `places = [locals()[name] for name in places_list]` That also works and it's less "evil" than `eval`. However, it's also not good practice - I would choose a completely different approach when there are lots of dicts. :)